# Convergence with increasing Lyapunov function

Tags: convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Given a (autonomous) dynamical system, one can prove instability of a point via the Lyapunov method, by simply finding a Lyapunov function that increases in a neighbourhood of the point. This ensures a stronger property than instability. It ensures the existence of a small enough neighbourhood, such that all orbits starting inside exit the neighbourhood at some time (instability only requires the existence of one such orbit, quite weaker).

My question is the following: does this stronger property allow that the system might converge (or approach) to the point in question? In other words, can a dynamical system converge (or approach) to a point admitting a neighbourhood with (strictly) increasing Lyapunov function? Thanks for any advice or reference.

EDIT: So far we proved that this cannot happen for continuous time systems. Is this also true for discrete time systems? Since the answer is in general settled to a no (continuous systems offer a counterexample as per the answer below) I will raise as a separate question the discrete case :  [Chetaev theorem for discrete time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864909/chetaev-theorem-for-discrete-time).

Comment: Something about your question is not making sense to me. If you have established that the point $0$ is unstable in the Lyapunov sense, then there is no convergence to point $0$. But, of course, the system could converge to *some other* point. Is that your question?

Comment: you can converge to a merely unstable point

Comment: Not disputing that. Your question isn't whether a merely unstable point has convergence for some trajectory. I'm clarifying whether your question is about the stronger property (Lyapunov unstable) as opposed to mere instability and whether you were concerned about convergence to the point 0 or some other point. In which case the answer is driven right from the definitions for point 0.

Comment: No, when I say unstable I always mean Lyapunov unstable, and a system can still converge to a Lyapunov unstable point. My question regards the (Lyapunov) unstable point itself only. The criterion, often named Lyapunov instability theorem (I know here the terminology is perhaps confusing), shows in fact a stronger property than (Lyapunov) instability, that is what I describe in the post. Does this stronger property of a point p allows for convergence of the system to the point p? The question is justified by the fact that you can converge to a Lyapunov unstable point.

Comment: One could rephrase the question as follows: can a system converge to a point satisfying the hypothesis of the Lyapunov instability theorem? (In the traditional wording, to avoid confusion, Lyapunov refers to theorem, not to instability)

Comment: Yup that was the confusion. I had thought you meant Lyapunov unstable in the sense you actually describe, but you are referring to the traditional condition as opposed to your modified condition (which, I have seen sometimes referred to as Lyapunov unstable confusingly enough)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the flavour of theorem you wish to invoke. For instance, here is a theorem from a nonlinear control text one could use,

> **Theorem 5.29 Instability Theorem.** The equilibrium point $0$ is unstable at time $t_0$ if there exists a decrescent function $V: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> 1. $\dot V(x,t)$ is locally positive definite, and
> 2. $V(0, t) = 0$ and there exists points $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that $v(x, t_0) > 0$

Indeed, this flavour only demands that there exists a one-dimensional unstable manifold passing through the origin (condition 2) since the positive definiteness is only assured on some set of points arbitrarily close to the origin. This does not preclude stability towards that set, for instance, including the origin along some set of measure zero. However, if you ask $V$ be locally positive definite except at $x = 0$, then that variant does not support convergence to the origin since all the points near the origin are expelled. The text I follow makes this comment:

> The instability theorems have the same flavor: They insist on $\dot V$ being an l.p.d.f. so as to have a mechanism for the increase of $V$. However, since we do not need to guarantee that every initial condition close to the origin is repelled from the origin, we do not need to assume that $V$ is an l.p.d.f.

So it boils down to what theorem you are choosing to use. In [2] there is further detailed comment to this effect for a very similarly stated theorem (although, not as precise as Sastry or Khalil were, so I will not quote the theorem).

> It is interesting to note that the function $V(\cdot)$ in Theorem 3.12 can be positive as well as negative in $D$. However, $V(·)$ is required to be positive for some points $x$ arbitrarily close to the origin of the nonlinear dynamical system. A more restrictive version of Theorem 3.12 is the case where $V : D \to R$ is positive definite for all $x\in B_\varepsilon(0)$. In this case, the zero solution $x(t) ≡ 0$ to (3.1) is completely unstable in the sense that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that every trajectory starting in $B_\varepsilon(0)$, other than the trivial trajectory, eventually leaves $B_\varepsilon(0)$.

The reason for this of course derives from the proof of instability. In proving Theorem 5.29, within any ball one picks $x(0)$ so that $V(0) > 0$. If it is the case that $V(0) > 0$ in an open neighbourhood of $0$ excluding $0$, then the proof can be applied to show all trajectories exit the neighbourhood.

[1]: S. Sastry. *Nonlinear Systems: Analysis, Stability and Control*. 1999.

[2]: W. M. Haddad and V. S. Chellaboina.
*Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Control.* 2008.

Comment: An equivalent theorem can be found in Khalil's text on Nonlinear Systems as well. See Theorem 3.3.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the references. Here lpdf means strictly bigger than  0 right? If so, Theorem 5.29 is weaker, in my understanding, because by points arbitrarily closed it is not meant a whole neighbourhood, say a ball centered at 0. In my version of the theorem, I mean a ball, so we fall into the interpretation of the last quote. Here every point 'eventually' (at some time large enough, potentially not uniformly across the points in the ball) leaves. But in principle, it could also return. Can we rule out convergence in this scenario?

Comment: Perhaps my use of convergence is a bit inappropriate here: I only mean a subsequence approaching the point in question. In essence, can we rule out, under these conditions, that the dynamical system displays a mechanism of leave and return that takes the orbit closer and closer to the point?

Comment: @xyz Correct. Fixing ourselves to time-invariant systems, lpdf = locally positive definite function [except for at the origin]. I see where you are going with this, but it would be ruled out unless you have a time-varying system. Remember, the solution curves inside the ball point outwards because of $\dot V > 0$, so no solution curve can get back into the ball. You need the weaker version of the theorem to see something interesting like that.

Comment: @xyz If you had a convergent subsequence, you'd also have found a subsequence of $V(t)$ which (eventually) decreases because $V$ is l.p.d.f. and $V(0)=0.$

Comment: Do you mean that by jumping in and out of the neighbourhood, the decrease incurred would have to be bounded away from zero and thus lead to negative values of V inside the neighbourhood in the long run?

Comment: @xyz The theorems I cite only refer to continuous time systems. If you are interested in discrete-time Lyapunov theory, I think you might want to specifically call that out in your question along with whatever theorem you are using because the discrete-time analogues are not as well-disseminated. I do believe your claim may be true in that case but I'd have to think about it more. I'll be deleting this answer in that case.

Comment: I think the only difference is that we do not need to specify the $V$ is decrescent. I am interested in both, but perhaps I find it easier to think of discrete systems, because I am more familiar with them. But even in the continuous case, where is that the contradiction emerges with jumping back in over and over, closer and closer to $0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151536/discussion-between-rollen-s-dsouza-and-xyz).

Comment: I will raise the discrete case in a separate question, I found a result that may be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864909/chetaev-theorem-for-discrete-time.